# ASP.NET Core MVC web app throws error while updating the database

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm following through a course to learn the framework stated above to make my school project. And I have an issue. I'm providing both the code and the issue below.

```
using E_Commerce.Data.Enums;
using E_Commerce.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace E_Commerce.Data
{
    public class AppDbInitializer
    {
        public static void Seed(IApplicationBuilder applicationBuilder)
        {
            using (var ServiceScope = applicationBuilder.ApplicationServices.CreateScope())
            {
                var context = ServiceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<AppDbContext>();

                context.Database.EnsureCreated();
                
                //Cinema
                if (!context.Cinemas.Any())
                {
                    context.Cinemas.AddRange(new List<Cinema>()
                    {
                        new Cinema()
                        {
                            Name = "Parliament Cinema Club",
                            Logo = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/tr/f/fd/Newparlies8.jpg",
                            Description =
                                "Parliament Sinema Kulübü, 1990'larda Star 1 kanalında, sinema filmlerinin her pazar gecesi televizyonda ilk kez gösterildiği sinema kuşağıdır. Jeneriğindeki Karla Bonoff tarafından seslendirilen All My Life parçası ve \"Parliament Sinema Kulübü, Pazar Gecesi Sineması'nı sunar.\" anonsuyla hafızalarda yer edinmiştir."
                        },
                        new Cinema()
                        {
                        Name = "Parliament Cinema Club2",
                        Logo = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/tr/f/fd/Newparlies8.jpg",
                        Description =
                            "Parliament Sinema Kulübü, 1990'larda Star 1 kanalında, sinema filmlerinin her pazar gecesi televizyonda ilk kez gösterildiği sinema kuşağıdır. Jeneriğindeki Karla Bonoff tarafından seslendirilen All My Life parçası ve \"Parliament Sinema Kulübü, Pazar Gecesi Sineması'nı sunar.\" anonsuyla hafızalarda yer edinmiştir."
                    }
                    });
                    context.SaveChanges();
                }

                //Actors
                if (!context.Actors.Any())
                {
                    context.Actors.AddRange(new List<Actor>()
                    {
                        new()
                        {
                            Name = "Cüneyt Arkın",
                            PicUrl =
                                "https://imgrosetta.mynet.com.tr/file/13311265/7b2270726f63657373223a7b2274797065223a2263726f70222c22636f6f7264696e61746573223a7b227831223a2230222c227931223a2230222c227832223a2230222c227932223a2230227d7d7d/1080xauto.jpg",
                            Bio =
                                "Cüneyt Arkın veya gerçek adıyla Fahrettin Cüreklibatır (d. 8 Eylül 1937), Türk sinema oyuncusu, senarist, yapımcı, yönetmen ve doktordur."
                        },
                        new()
                        {
                        Name = "Murat Arkın",
                        PicUrl =
                            "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMGJhOTZhYmQtN2QwNy00M2I5LWE5YzQtYzVmNTNiZjRkYTQzXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNDg4MjkzNDk@._V1_.jpg",
                        Bio =
                            "Murat Arkın (gerçek adı: Murat Cüreklibatur; d. 4 Mayıs 1975, İstanbul), Türk oyuncudur. Sinemada canlandırdığı Malkoçoğlu karakteri ile tanınan Cüneyt Arkın'ın oğludur."
                    }
                    });
                    context.SaveChanges();
                }

                //Producers
                if (!context.Producers.Any())
                {
                    context.Producers.AddRange(new List<Producer>()
                    {
                        new()
                        {
                            Name = "Kerem Çatay",
                            PicUrl =
                                "https://imgrosetta.mynet.com.tr/file/13311265/7b2270726f63657373223a7b2274797065223a2263726f70222c22636f6f7264696e61746573223a7b227831223a2230222c227931223a2230222c227832223a2230222c227932223a2230227d7d7d/1080xauto.jpg",
                            Bio =
                                "Cüneyt Arkın veya gerçek adıyla Fahrettin Cüreklibatır (d. 8 Eylül 1937), Türk sinema oyuncusu, senarist, yapımcı, yönetmen ve doktordur."
                        },
                        new()
                        {
                            Name = "Kerem Çatay2",
                            PicUrl =
                                "https://imgrosetta.mynet.com.tr/file/13311265/7b2270726f63657373223a7b2274797065223a2263726f70222c22636f6f7264696e61746573223a7b227831223a2230222c227931223a2230222c227832223a2230222c227932223a2230227d7d7d/1080xauto.jpg",
                            Bio =
                                "Cüneyt Arkın veya gerçek adıyla Fahrettin Cüreklibatır (d. 8 Eylül 1937), Türk sinema oyuncusu, senarist, yapımcı, yönetmen ve doktordur."
                        }
                    });
                    context.SaveChanges();
                }

                //Movies
                if (!context.Movies.Any())
                {
                    context.Movies.AddRange(new List<Movie>()
                    {
                        new()
                        {
                            Name = "Saving Private Ryan",
                            PicUrl =
                                "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BZjhkMDM4MWItZTVjOC00ZDRhLThmYTAtM2I5NzBmNmNlMzI1XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNDYyMDk5MTU@._V1_FMjpg_UX1000_.jpg",
                            Description =
                                "Er Ryan'ı Kurtarmak (İngilizce: Saving Private Ryan), Steven Spielberg tarafından yönetilerek Robert Rodat tarafından yazılan, II. Dünya Savaşı konulu bir epik savaş filmidir.",
                            MovieCategory = MovieCategory.Action,
                            
                },
                        new()
                        {
                            Name = "Space Jam",
                            PicUrl =
                                "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMDgyZTI2YmYtZmI4ZC00MzE0LWIxZWYtMWRlZWYxNjliNTJjXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNjY5NDU4NzI@._V1_.jpg",
                            Description =
                                "Space Jam, 1996 ABD yapımı bir animasyon filmdir. Başrolünde Michael Jordan, Bugs Bunny (seslendirme Billy West) ve diğer Looney Tunes karakterleri vardır. Filmin yapımcısı Ivan Reitman, yönetmeni Joe Pytka'dir.",
                            MovieCategory = MovieCategory.Animation,
                            
                        }
                    });
                    context.SaveChanges();
                }

                //Actors_Movies
                if (!context.Actors_Movies.Any())
                {
                    context.Actors_Movies.AddRange(new List<Actor_Movie>()
                    {
                        new Actor_Movie()
                        {
                           MovieId = 1,
                           ActorId = 1
                        },
                       
                    });
                    context.SaveChanges();
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to run the app, it points to the `SaveChanges` function at the last part of Movie creation and throws this:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: 'An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.'
>
> SqlException: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Movies_Cinemas_CinemaId". The conflict occurred in database "CommerceDB", table "dbo.Cinemas", column 'Id'.

As far as I understand I'm trying to make a movie shown in the cinema which has the same id, but since the cinema with that id hasn't been created yet, I can't update the database. I know so little SQL that I better say that I don't.

So I need a solution that doesn't include any manual SQL. I followed the course line by line except the info I add to the columns are different. But I don't think that causes the issue.

Here is a diagram of my database:

[image]

Here's the code for migration:

```
// <auto-generated />
using System;
using E_Commerce.Data;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ValueConversion;

namespace E_Commerce.Migrations
{
    [DbContext(typeof(AppDbContext))]
    [Migration("20211218061214_TryChangeFK")]
    partial class TryChangeFK
    {
        protected override void BuildTargetModel(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
#pragma warning disable 612, 618
            modelBuilder
                .HasAnnotation("Relational:MaxIdentifierLength", 128)
                .HasAnnotation("ProductVersion", "5.0.6")
                .HasAnnotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn);

            modelBuilder.Entity("E_Commerce.Models.Actor", b =>
                {
                    b.Property<int>("Id")
                        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                        .HasColumnType("int")
                        .HasAnnotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn);

                    b.Property<string>("Bio")
                        .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");

                    b.Property<string>("Name")
                        .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");

                    b.Property<string>("PicUrl")
                        .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");

                    b.HasKey("Id");

                    b.ToTable("Actors");
                });

            modelBuilder.Entity("E_Commerce.Models.Actor_Movie", b =>
                {
                    b.Property<int>("ActorId")
                        .HasColumnType("int");

                    b.Property<int>("MovieId")
                        .HasColumnType("int");

                    b.HasKey("ActorId", "MovieId");

                    b.HasIndex("MovieId");

                    b.ToTable("Actors_Movies");
                });

            modelBuilder.Entity("E_Commerce.Models.Cinema", b =>
                {
                    b.Property<int>("Id")
                        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                        .HasColumnType("int")
                        .HasAnnotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn);

                    b.Property<string>("Description")
                        .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");

                    b.Property<string>("Logo")
                        .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");

                    b.Property<string>("Name")
                        .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");

                    b.HasKey("Id");

                    b.ToTable("Cinemas");
                });

            modelBuilder.Entity("E_Commerce.Models.Movie", b =>
                {
                    b.Property<int>("Id")
                        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                        .HasColumnType("int")
                        .HasAnnotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn);

                    b.Property<int>("CinemaId")
                        .HasColumnType("int");

                    b.Property<string>("Description")
                        .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");

                    b.Property<DateTime>("EndDate")
                        .HasColumnType("datetime2");

                    b.Property<int>("MovieCategory")
                        .HasColumnType("int");

                    b.Property<string>("Name")
                        .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");

                    b.Property<string>("PicUrl")
                        .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");

                    b.Property<double>("Price")
                        .HasColumnType("float");

                    b.Property<int>("ProducerId")
                        .HasColumnType("int");

                    b.Property<DateTime>("StartDate")
                        .HasColumnType("datetime2");

                    b.HasKey("Id");

                    b.HasIndex("CinemaId");

                    b.HasIndex("ProducerId");

                    b.ToTable("Movies");
                });

            modelBuilder.Entity("E_Commerce.Models.Producer", b =>
                {
                    b.Property<int>("Id")
                        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                        .HasColumnType("int")
                        .HasAnnotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn);

                    b.Property<string>("Bio")
                        .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");

                    b.Property<string>("Name")
                        .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");

                    b.Property<string>("PicUrl")
                        .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");

                    b.HasKey("Id");

                    b.ToTable("Producers");
                });

            modelBuilder.Entity("E_Commerce.Models.Actor_Movie", b =>
                {
                    b.HasOne("E_Commerce.Models.Actor", "Actor")
                        .WithMany("Actors_Movies")
                        .HasForeignKey("ActorId")
                        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
                        .IsRequired();

                    b.HasOne("E_Commerce.Models.Movie", "Movie")
                        .WithMany("Actors_Movies")
                        .HasForeignKey("MovieId")
                        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
                        .IsRequired();

                    b.Navigation("Actor");

                    b.Navigation("Movie");
                });

            modelBuilder.Entity("E_Commerce.Models.Movie", b =>
                {
                    b.HasOne("E_Commerce.Models.Cinema", "Cinema")
                        .WithMany("Movies")
                        .HasForeignKey("CinemaId")
                        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
                        .IsRequired();

                    b.HasOne("E_Commerce.Models.Producer", "Producer")
                        .WithMany("Movies")
                        .HasForeignKey("ProducerId")
                        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
                        .IsRequired();

                    b.Navigation("Cinema");

                    b.Navigation("Producer");
                });

            modelBuilder.Entity("E_Commerce.Models.Actor", b =>
                {
                    b.Navigation("Actors_Movies");
                });

            modelBuilder.Entity("E_Commerce.Models.Cinema", b =>
                {
                    b.Navigation("Movies");
                });

            modelBuilder.Entity("E_Commerce.Models.Movie", b =>
                {
                    b.Navigation("Actors_Movies");
                });

            modelBuilder.Entity("E_Commerce.Models.Producer", b =>
                {
                    b.Navigation("Movies");
                });
#pragma warning restore 612, 618
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance to whoever is gonna tackle this issue!

Answer (score -1):

Issue is solved. I wasn't giving it any Cinema or Producer Id's to connect with. It's working when i add CinemaId=1, ProducerId=1 to the new movie for example.

Comment: Don't forget that you need to make a new migration and then update the database before trying